# Download a file using asynctask and showing progressbar

Tags: android

i have a following code to download an image , show a progress bar and return its bitmap. but the bitmap always returns null.. once i remove the while loop, the bitmap has value, but i dont get a progress bar.

```
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    bitmap = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/DCIM/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);

        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.e("could not  load ", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

public void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Before BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input), you need to reset the inputstream or re-open it.

Comment: Instead of `ProgressBar` can you use `ProgressDialog`?. I think there's some problem with `lenghtOfFile`. Please post the `exceptions`

Comment: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
 only this is being shown in logcat, and in this device nothing is showing up after running the progressbar. when i debugged, i could see that, after bitmap deocde, the complier move to return nulll in catch{}

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an InputStream can only read one time. you need to change your code to :

```
   while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);

    }

    output.flush();

    String pathName=Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/DCIM/downloadedfile.jpg";
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need interface because asynctask can return bitmap.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

     return downloadBitmap();
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     super.onPostExecute(result);
 }
```

When you call task you must use get();

```
Bitmap bitmap = new DownloadFileTask().execute().get();
```

Comment: One **SHOULD NOT** use `get()`, it hangs the UI.

Comment: This is not a long hangs maybe 300ms,get() calling only onPost method and onPost is running on main thread so hangs is normal.If you don't want to hangs ui you can open new thread!

Comment: AsyncTask runs on different thread. There won't be any hangs while using `onPostExecute()`. How can you be so sure of `300ms`? It depends on the content being accessed, right? Using `get` is **BAD PRACTICE**

Comment: Right,it depends on the content being accessed.The content being accessed is a bitmap and I'm sure it will not take more than 300ms so user can't catch it.

Comment: Nobody was talking about an interface. And indeed using get() on an AsyncTask is a very bad idea.